# Set DataSourceCredentials in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

Can I specify `DataSourceCredentials` in `Webforms`? I'm used to work with `WinForms`, but in `WebFroms` the `DataSourceCredentials` object is read only.

I'm embedding a report in ASPX page and trying to specify the datasource in code.

Thanks